# Efficient switch case for nil in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three variables all of which can be nil:

```
to
cc
bcc
```

How can I assign `X` to any one of the to/cc/bcc given that any one of them can be nil (but not all three)? It seems ugly to do

```
if to.nil? and cc.nil?
   X = bcc
elsif ...
```

You can't do

```
 X = to or cc or bcc
```

either.

Comment: Do you realize that `X` is a constant, rather than a variable? `x` would be a variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yo can do this:

```
X = (to or cc or bcc)
```

Or this:

```
X = to || cc || bcc
```

`||` has higher precedence than `=`, `or` — lower, so first example doesn't work without parentheses, X is just unconditionally assigned to first variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

```
x = [to, cc, bcc].find{|address| ! address.nil?}
```

Comment: You could do `x = [to, cc, bcc].find { |address| address }`. :)